# Как правильно проверить наличие знака в строке в Бате?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, windows, bat

**Моя ситуация:** Я работаю с 8ми серверами и скачиваю много инофрмации ежедневно. Для этого я прописал бат который подсоединяет меня ко всемю

```
net use "\\serv01.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes
net use "\\serv02.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes
...
```

В последнее время понадобилось часто подсоединяться только к 1му из них.
В голову пришла идея передавать сервера к которым надо подсоединиться как (одного) аргумент в виде числа типа "145"(первый, четвертый и пятый сервера).

**Вопрос:** Могу ли я проверить переменную servers на наличие конкретного числа в ней? Что-то вроде:

```
if 1 in %servers% (net use "\\serv01.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes)
if 2 in %servers% (net use "\\serv02.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes)
...
```

К сожалению мои личные поски в гугле завядт менв решения которые не работают и которые я сам не могу понять:

```
  IF NOT x%servers:1=%==x%servers% ( do stuff() )
```

Есть ли более елегантное решение моей проблемы?
Буду признателен за советы или ссылки на сайты, которые я бы мог использовать для самообучения.

Comment: А сервера действительно имеют такой вид serv01.com serv02.com и т.д. Т.е. оканчиваются цифрой? Это упростило бы задачу

Comment: Нет, сервера имеют вид ссссссNN.ccccc.cccccc.com. Где "c" это буквы, а "N" это цифры. Цифры изменятся 01 до 08.

Comment: т.е. вводя параметром 12 вы хотите заюзать сссссс01.ccccc.cccccc.com и сссссс02.ccccc.cccccc.com? Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Да, именно. Такая моя идея.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать перебрать по-очереди передаваемые символы в аргументе:

```
@echo off

set var=%1
call :net_use_to_serv "%var%"
pause
goto :eof

:net_use_to_serv
  set t=%~1
  if "%t%"=="" exit /B
  \\ccccc0%t:~,1%.ccccc.cccccc.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes
    call :net_use_to_serv "%t:~1%"
Exit /B
```

т.о. запуская `script.bat 12` мы получим

> \ccccc01.ccccc.cccccc.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes
>   \ccccc02.ccccc.cccccc.com\D$" %pass% /user:%login% /persistent:yes

Comment: Я правильно понимаю - это рекурсивный бат, который с помощью %t:~,1% берет первое число из аргкмента, а %t:~1% передает строку без первого дальше в рекурсию?

Comment: да, совершенно верно

Comment: Будет ли это работать, если я не передам вообще никакого аргумента? Есть ли в бате различия между пустой строкой и NULL как в Java? [ "" != NULL ] в Java

Comment: я привел данный батник, как пример решения той проблемы, которую вы описали. Но, естественно, надо оградить от использования неверных аргументов. Передав пустую строку ( т.е. запустив без аргументов)  батник просто завершиться. Это раз, а во-вторых откуда в bat NULL?

Comment: Я новичек в bat мире и пришел из мира java. Поэтому я пока все фижу через призму этого языка. Ваш способ работает, Спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста! Что бы проще было, просто помните, что bat это всего лишь язык описания сценариев. Но, если вам нужны более сложные и более удобные решения, то стоит обратить внимание в Windows на VBS и PowerShell

Comment: Что избежать проблемы совместимости с программами вызывающими этот бат и для удобности ввел строку: IF [%servers%]==[] (SET servers=12345678) Так можно передавать путой аргумент и это будет значит "все сервера"